# MySQL Insert un-trusted data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, owasp

I see a lot of post about inserting into MySQL database. The vast amount of them seem to forget that its user input we are dealing with. What would be the best was to insert data in to the table. Would `mysqli_real_escape_string` be okay? Or would using prepared statements be a better option, maybe both?

Comment: Escaping is not okay. Using both even less. Use Prepared, parameterized Queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_real_escape_string`  is good, but not always safe as prepared  statement.

`mysql_real_escape_string()` prone to the same kind of issues affecting `addslashes()`.

So use of ***prepared statement*** is much better.